# Hide and Show list menu items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have simple vertical menu using list elements like below

```
<ul id="leftNav">
    <li id="home"><a href="/index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="apples"><a href="/category/apples.html">Apples</a>

        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="/category/red-apples.html">Red Apples</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/category/green-apples.html">Green Apples</a> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="/category/golden-apples.html">Golden Apples</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="grapes"><a href="/category/grapes.html">Grapes</a>

        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="/category/red-grapes.html">Red Grapes</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/category/green-grapes.html">Green Grapes</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/category/black-grapes.html">Black Grapes</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dry-fruits"><a href="/category/dry-fruits.html">Dry Fruits</a>

        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li id="subParent1"><a href="#">Fruits That Are Dried</a>

                <ul class="subMenu1">
                    <li><a href="/category/figs.html">Figs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/category/dates.html">Dates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/category/pineapples.html">Pine Apples</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="subParent2"><a href="#">Nuts and Seeds</a>

                <ul class="subMenu1">
                    <li><a href="/category/chestnuts.html">Chestnuts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/category/almonds.html">Almonds</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/category/walnuts.html">Walnuts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="subParent3"><a href="/category/bananas.html">Bananas</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="sale" class="expanded"><a href="/category/sale.html">Sale</a>

</ul>
```

What I am trying to do is when apples or its sub items are clicked I am trying keep that sections of the list expanded and so on, so when Grapes or its sub items are clicked all other should be closed except Grapes section.

I tried using code like below, but since Apples and Grapes are links which render their respective pages, my code below is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#apples .subMenu").css("display", "block");
});
```

Any help or example or advice is appreciated.

Comment: fyi, you can use .show() instead of .css(). same thing with hiding: .hide()

Comment: check this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ & search in google **accordion js**

Comment: Do you want disable `<a>`'s link? You can try to add [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of all the links? Since all the list elements you are speaking of are also links, should clicking only collapse them or what is the idea?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. I am sorry I did not explain properly. What I what is basically when some one clicks on APPLES they should go the APPLES page and its sub items should be EXPANDED. and stay EXPANDED if any of its sub items are clicked and go their page. So if I click on GREEN APPLES, I should go to GREEN APPLES and at the same time have the entire APPLES section EXPANDED while the rest of the menu is COLLAPSED, Repeat the process in the same manner with others too, THANKS a BUNCH!!!

Comment: Ok I have worked on it here is my test site. if you click the left nav you can see i got it work 90%. I changed the menu from list to using div's. The only place i am stuck is if you click on dry fruits and click on the sub menu say nuts and seeds, its sub menu shows up but if I click on any on the sub-items like walnuts, the menu gets collapsed , not sure how to keep it open when the second level sub items are clicked. Thanks and appreciate it. links for preview is http://store.cotintheweb.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You constantly reload page - and the javascript reloads too. If you want to save the state of the menu between requests use cookies.

Or here is a version without reloading the page - then you have to use Ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#left-navigation a').click(function(){
     return false;
    });

    $(".parent-grapes > a, .parent-apples > a, .parent-dry-fruits > a").click(function () {
    var $block = $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu");
    $block.toggle();

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
      $('#main-content').html($(data).find('#main-content').html());
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The menu requires only this javascript (and JQuery)

Answer (score 2):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#apples > a").on('click',function(e){
            $('#apples .subMenu ').toggle();
            return false;
         });
      }); 
   </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/makedone/WRcBa/

Comment: Thanks Makedon, I will try your sample too. Appreciate it

Comment: Ok I have worked on it here is my test site. if you click the left nav you can see i got it work 90%. I changed the menu from list to using div's. The only place i am stuck is if you click on dry fruits and click on the sub menu say nuts and seeds, its sub menu shows up but if I click on any on the sub-items like walnuts, the menu gets collapsed , not sure how to keep it open when the second level sub items are clicked. Thanks and appreciate it. links for preview is http://store.cotintheweb.com

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$("#parent-apples .sub-menu").show();
$("a#FTAD").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();  var $parent = $(this).parent('.sub-menu');$parent.find(".sub-menu1").show();
$parent.find(".sub-menu2").hide();
});
$("a#NS").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); var $parent = $(this).parent('.sub-menu');$parent.find(".sub-menu1").hide();
$parent.find(".sub-menu2").show();
});
$("#parent-apples #subParent1").css("display", "block");
$("#parent-apples #subParent2").css("display", "block");
});

Comment: I tried your code sir. Now If I click nuts and seeds, nothing happens. you can see in the link I posted. Thanks appreciate your help in this regard

Comment: says $parent.find can't find

Comment: sorry sir but I can't see the code where you used AJAX. thank and appreciate it

Comment: $parent don't found, because page was reload

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

try this. It worked for me..

Thanks! @leo.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            hideAll();

             $("#leftNav li a").click( function(e) {
               try {

                  var pid = $(this).parent('li').attr("id");
                  //alert(pid);
                  if(pid == undefined) {

                  } else {
                    hideAll();
                    $("#" + pid + " .submenu").show();
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }

               } catch(e) {
                alert("oops!");
               }
            });
        }); 


        function hideAll() { 
             $(".subMenu").hide();
        }

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and see what happens