# Is it possible to only show 1 q on a page at a time?

Tags: php, html

So i need to build a website, but I have the skills of a beginner. Nevertheless, my plan is to display only 1 question at a time on a page, so other students can't see what the user has filled in. Is it possible to display the next question, without moving to another page, so the current question dissapears and the next question appears, because I think putting all the questions in 1 html file is the best way to do this.
If there is a quicker/easier way, please tell me.

-Dion van der Riet

Comment: Everything is possible. If you want to update the page without a reload you need to use javascript

Comment: You don't need to make one page per question in real life. You just need to echo one at the time and keep a counter on which question the student is on. Keep in mind that javascript is visible for the student, if you go that route, do not keep the answer in javascript. The test needs to be corrected on the server (php).

Comment: Adding to the point made by @JimL, also look up Jquery, considering `so the current question dissapears and the next question appears,`

Answer (score 1):

So here is a simple way:

- Just a plain HTML page, with [a list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) of [hidden questions.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)
- Use JavaScript to hide the current question and show the next. This might be a little complicated but [here is JQuery example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423583/hide-and-show-list-menu-items-using-jquery) and you could Google dozens of others. JQuery is just JavaScript, and you can pick it up in no time.

But already there is a little complexity to this if you are a complete beginner. I'd suggest heading over https://www.codecademy.com/ and do the courses on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

As Jim commented, anything is possible so the answer to your question is yes. If you've done a quiz on Buzzfeed or numerous other sites it's been done. You've tagged php and html so I'm guessing you want to build a basic site, with hardcoded questions, and you want some kind of transition such that only a single question shows at a time.

That said if you just want to show a list of questions, there are numerous sites out there for free that will do this for you.

Good luck, and shoot me any questions you might have.

Comment: I have tried the method you linked above, but because I lack in things I know of java, I'm just struggling to make it work. Wouldn't it be better if I "just" put 1 question per page, but the user needs to click to the next page, and even to the previous page? My question here is if it will
1) Take a long time to make, considering I need to finish it tomorrow.
2)  Not be really hard to eventually send all the scores from every radio button to one final form, that calculates the score and sends the mail with score from every student to the teacher.

Comment: I hear you. 

1. It would be simpler* to do just as you suggest - have a different html page for each question and link between them. This would save you from having to delve into the JavaScript.

This might be a good prototype so you can get around the basics of HTML. Keep in mind that this approach is just to get you going, there would be 'better' approaches to take.

At minimum you are going to need to know basic HTML and how forms work. Definitely checkout http://www.w3schools.com/ and https://www.codecademy.com/ .

Comment: On 2) http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail . This a good very basic implementation of what you are asking for. Remember that the 'hiding' of questions is just a presentation thing and to do that you will require some JavaScript to manage it